# what is the best way to fetch property list from json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach, lodash

I want to fetch a property list from a json array.
below is json array

[
  {
    treeName: 'tree_A',
    prefix: 'prefix'
  },
  {
    treeName: 'tree_b',
    prefix: 'prefix1/'
  }
]

After running code, my expectation result is ["tree_A","tree_B"];

Below is my implementation:

```
var treeNames = [];
        for (var index = 0; index < config.treeSources.length; index++) {
            treeNames.push(config.treeSources[index].treeName);
        }
```

I want to find a best implementation to make code beautiful..

any one want to play it?

Comment: lodash version:`_.forEach(config.treeSources, function (source) {
                treeNames1.push(source.treeName);
            });`

Comment: is there any function in javascript like C# lambda `var result = list.select(x=>x.treeNmae).list();`?

Comment: *"I want to find a best implementation to make code beautiful'* How do you define "best"? Is the "best" implementation the shortest? The one the uses the least memory? Least CPU? The one that is most compatible with existing runtimes?

Comment: Actually I want "to make code beautiful". it looks like short and have good a understanding, but your question is useful for me(new boy in javascript). It makes my eyes brightened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Lodash](https://lodash.com/)/[Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)'s [`_.pluck`](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck) function. It does exactly what you want:

```
var treeNames = _.pluck(config.treeSources, 'treeName')
```

Using an entire utility library like Lodash or Underscore is probably overkill if your only going to use it for this one function, however, although they do provide a wide variety of very useful other functions.

Comment: Please, if this answer solves your question, set it as the accepted answer by clicking the green tick beside the question ;)

Comment: you can avoid lodash if all you need is pluck: `function pluck(x){ "use strict"; return x[this];}`, then use it anytime with [].map() (or filter): `config.treeSources.map(pluck, 'treeName');`

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it something like bellow using native [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var data = [ { treeName: 'tree_A', prefix: 'prefix' }, { treeName: 'tree_b', prefix: 'prefix1/' } ];
var treeNames = data.map(function (tree) {
    return tree.treeName;
});

console.log(treeNames);
```

**Note:-** The IE8 doesn't support **map** function, so if want this on IE8 you have to use native **for** loop or some library like **underscorejs**.